# Java: General Inheritance/Casting (ResourceBundle)

Tags: java, inheritance, subclassing, resourcebundle

I am getting some CastClassExceptions. I think my understanding of subclassing in confused and could use some clarification. I have the following classes:

```
// defined in java.util
abstract class ResourceBundle {
 ...
} 

// defined in java.util
class PropertyResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {
 ...
}

// defined by myself
class ResourceBundleWrapper extends ResourceBundle {
 ...  
  // abstract in ResourceBundle
  @Override public Enumeration<String> getKeys() { 
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  // abstract in ResourceBundle
  @Override protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  // protected in ResourceBundle
  public Set<String> handleKeySet() {
    ...
    the code from ResourceBundle.handleKeySet()
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The purpose of the wrapper class is to expose the handleKeySet() method so that I can get the keys of a bundle without in addition, getting the keys of its parent bundle. 
I have roughly the following code:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = getBundle(); // method can return any subclass of ResourceBundle
```

I would like to be able to get the keys of *bundle* by casting it to a ResourceBundleWrapper. I cannot cast bundle to type ResourceBundleWrapper without getting a ClassCastException. Example error message:

```
java.util.PropertyResourceBundle cannot be cast to com.common.ResourceBundleWrapper
```

I understand why this cast exception is happening. That is not what I need clarification on. How do I achieve what I am trying to achieve with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PropertyResourceBundle and ResourceBundleWrapper are each descendents of ResourceBudle, so they can each do ResourceBundle's job. However there is no reason to suppose that they replacements for 
each other. So the cast you are attempting is invalid.

Could you instead have PropertyResourceBundle extend ResourceBundleWrapper? Then your class can benefit from the additional capabilities of the wrapper.

Comment: No, I can not. PropertyResourceBundle is not my own class. It is defined in java.util. Furthermore, like I said, getBundle() can return ANY subclass of ResourceBundle, so we can not count on on that object being of type PropertyResourceBundle.

Answer (score 0):

PropertyResourceBundle and ResourceBundleWrapper are both ResourceBundeles.
Thnik on a class that is has parent Fruit and has Mango and Kiwi as child classes.
Mango is not Kiwi :) and Kiwi is not Mango but both are fruits :)